# Extract bounding box coordinates and area from an annotated image

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, detection

I am working on an object-detection task and I need to extract from an annotated image(an image with the bounding box already drawed around the object) the coordinates of the bounding box and its area. Anyone have an idea about how to do that?

This is an example of the image:
[image]

Thanks.

The problem is that i can't find out how to detect the bounding box in the image. Moreover I want to detect only the bounding box and not other contours. I tried this code, but it just crop the image in the direction of the bounding box:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

large = cv2.imread('WhatsApp-Image-2023-07-13-at-10.59.04.jpg')
small = cv2.cvtColor(large, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(small, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

_, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 1))
connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_contour)

cv2.rectangle(large, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 255, 0), 1)
roi = large[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imshow('Bounding Box', roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you add to the question the things you have already tried?

Comment: I modified the question.

Comment: And what is the output you get from that code?

Comment: A new image cropped around the bounding box. But is not cropped well. Moreover i want the coordinates on a list, i don't want the image

Comment: By the way, where does the image with the BB cmoe from, becouse when the BB is generated usually you can ask for the coordenates as well

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that there are somewhere file that contain the coordinates that you are looking for.

If not, you could transform your image to grayscale, find the unique values, count those values and take the pixel value with the most counts -> this is the color of your bounding box, as there pixels have exactly the same pixel values.

When you know the bounding box color, you can make mask the image accordingly, apply eroding (to loose pixels that have by cooincidence the very same color) and then you find the last remaining object on the mask. This is your bounding box.